# Negative array indexing and placement in memory (pointing)

Tags: memory, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

In fortran you can declare an array with any suitable (integral) range, for example:

```
real* 8 array(-10:10)
```

I believe that fortran, when passing by reference, will always pass around array(1) as the reference, but I'm not sure.

I'm using fortran pointers, and I believe that fortran is pointing the "1st" element address, i.e. array(1), not array(-10). However I'm not sure.

How does Fortran deal with negative array indexing in memory? And is it implimentation defined?

Edit: To add a little more detail, I'm passing a malloc'd block from C to fortran by means of using a fortran pointer to point at the the address, which is done by calling a fortran routine from within C. I.e. C goes:

```
void * pointer = malloc(blockSize*sizeof(double));
fortranpoint_(pointer);
```

And the fortran point routine looks like:

```
real*8 :: target block(5, -6:6, 0:0)
real*8 :: pointer array(:,:,:)

entry fortranPoint(block)
array => block
return
```

The problem is that sometimes when it later tries to access say:

```
array(1, -6, 0)
```

I am not sure if this is accessing the address at the beginning of the block or somewhere before it. I now think this is implementation defined, but would like to know the details of each implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortran array argument ABI depends on the compiler, and perhaps more crucially, on whether the called procedure has an explicit or implicit interface.

For an implicit interface, typically the address of the first element is passed [1]. In the callee, the procedure then adds an offset depending on how the array dummy argument is declared. E.g. if the array dummy argument is declared somearray(-10:10), then a reference to somearray(x) is calculated as

```
address_of_first_element_passed_in_to_the_procedure + x + 10
```

If the procedure has an explicit interface, typically an array descriptor structure is passed rather than the address of the first element. In this structure, the callee can find information on the bounds of each dimension and, of course, a pointer to the actual data, allowing it to calculate the correct offset, similarly to the case of an implicit interface.

[1] Note that this is the first element in memory, that is, the lowest index for each dimension. Not somearray(1) regardless of how the array was declared.

To answer your updated question, for C/Fortran interoperability, use the ISO_C_BINDING feature which is nowadays widely available. This provides a standardized way to pass information between C and Fortran.

Comment: Would using ISO_C_BINDING require me to change the data types that I'm using within the Fortran? I've looked it up briefly and I can't tell. I'm a C programmer that's having to work with some Fortran, which I cannot edit on such a large scale as changing the data types.

Comment: Well, you need to make sure that the types and kinds match, yes. But I don't see that as a particularly big problem. E.g. if the C code uses doubles, the ISO_C_BINDING stuff should use REAL(kind=C_DOUBLE) and then you need to make sure that REAL(kind=C_DOUBLE) is the same kind as the Fortran procedure you're binding to uses. Note that the kinds are just integer parameters; on most compilers today, KIND(1.0d0) == C_DOUBLE == selected_real_kind(15) == 8, so most likely you're good to go.

Comment: ISO_C_BINDING does not exist on one of my target platforms, so I can't write code involving it, unfortunately. Do you have any idea where I could find information detailing which compiler does what with it's arrays?
In tandem with that, I've not heard the terms "implicit" and "explicit" interface before. What do they mean?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the dummy argument for a regular array in Fortran is declared A(:) (or with more dimensions), the SHAPE is passed, not the specific index range.   So the procedure will default to one-indexing.   You can override this with a declaration in the procedure of A(-10:), or A(StartIndex:), where StartIndex is another argument.

Fortran pointers do include the index range, but the passing mechanism will be compiler dependent.  Code interfacing this to C is likely to be OS & compiler dependent.   As already suggested, I'd use a regular array and the ISO C Binding.   It is MUCH easier than the old ways of figuring out the compiler passing mechanisms and standard and portable.    If you have a large existing Fortran code, you could write a "glue" Fortran procedure that maps between the regular Fortran variable declarations and the ISO C Binding names.   While they types will have formally different names, in practice they will be the same if you select the correct ISO C types.  The ISO C Binding has been available for many years now -- can you upgrade the compiler on the problem target platform?  If not, I'd use a regular Fortran array and either use zero-indexing on the C-side, or explicitly pass as arguments the desired indices.

There are examples of ISO C Binding usage on other Stack Overflow questions.

The interface to a procedure is explicit if it is declared so that it is known to the compiler in the caller.   The simplest way it to place the procedures in a module and "use" the module in the caller.  Having explicit interfaces helps avoid bugs since the compiler can check consistency between arguments of the caller and callee.   It is a little bit like C header files, only easier.